# What affects the color of the input source icon in Ventura?

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar, internationalization, input-source

I noticed that on my machine the icon of the ABC and U.S. input source (either set as default) has a filled in background, but on my friend's machine the same input source has a clear background. I've been unable to locate any correlation for this between macOS versions, wallpaper colors and system theme, and all the screenshots online seem to randomly have it filled in or transparent. Hopefully the screenshot makes it more clear:

[image: comparison of two icons]

Comment: Looks like reduced transparency to me.

Comment: @red_menace neither system has reduced transparency on

Comment: As far as I can see: primary language is filled, secondary is not filled - try and change the order in System Settings > General > Language & Region > Preferred Languages.